# Приложение Angular. Ошбики в консоли

Tags: angular, angular-material, datetimepicker

Я пишу приложение Angular + Yii2, у меня почти готова форма редактирования кандидата, но я никак не могу избавиться от ошибок, которые вываливаются в консоль:
[image: Ошибка связанная с тем - что данные приходят не сразу]

Я попытался воспользоваться elvis оператором - и получил в консоли следующую ошибку- мой инпут:

```
<input class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="candidate?.lastname" (ngModelChange)="save()" placeholder="Фамилия" />
```

Ошибка: 
[image: Ошибка при использовании оператора ?.]

Почитав на SO ответы по этой ошибке - я нашел следующий вариант - ко всем инпутам добавить проверку - например так:

```
*ngIf="candidate"
```

Но проблема в том, что у меня на форме еще есть Angular Material Date Picker, который при добавлении данной проверки - выдает следующую ошибку:
[image: Ошибка Date Time Picker]

Почитав ответы на SO и по этой ошибке - я пришел к выводу - что она связана с тем - что внутри input  находится *ngIf.
Мой Date Time Picker:

```
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" *ngIf="candidate" [(ngModel)]="candidate.date_birth" (ngModelChange)="save()" placeholder="Дата рождения">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста - как правильно избавится от этих проблем - буду благодарен за любое решение!!!!

Comment: В чем проблема `mat-form-field` обернуть в `ngIf`? Приводи, пожалуйста, вместо скриншотов - воспроизводимые примеры, уже глаза режет смотреть на них...

Comment: хорошо - постараюсь исправить!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Весь компонент можно обернуть в

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="candidate">
  <input class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="candidate.lastname" (ngModelChange)="save()" placeholder="Фамилия" />

  Другие инпуты тут тоже находятся
</ng-container>
```